# how can I generate a Picturebox[] Array by a Code?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, element

I want to make a Program which mixes cards and then resets them(like in the beginning). I made 52 Picturebox and in each should be a .png File. My Program would mix the cards by changing the Position of each Picturebox randomly.

The Problem:
I want to give each Array the Data of another Picturebox

something like this:

```
PictureBox[] cards = new PictureBox[52];

cards[0] = PictureBox1;
cards[1] = PictureBox2;
cards[2] = PictureBox3;

and so on until it would reach 52.
```

Is there a way to make it automatically? I thought maybe with a for-loop.
Something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 53; i++)
   
  cards[i]= Picturebox.i
```

I know that I can't just write an i after the Picturebox but maybe you know a method and very important: please try to use the same structure. Like if it's possible to change as less as possible

Comment: I'd reconsider the design.  Cards are Cards - they are going to have a Value, Rank, Suit and optionally an image.  A Picturebox is just how you display any given card - it can only handle *one* of those properties.  And, you only need one for each card *dealt*.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You are propably trying to make a game. As disclaimer: Windows Forms is not suited for game development. A simple cardgame might actually still work. But there is no guarantee. The big part about creating the PictureBox is actually adding it to the form too. `cards[i]= Picturebox.i ` should look like: `cards[i]= new Picturebox();` You propably tried to give names like "PictureBox1", "PictureBox2", etc. But taht is unessesrary. You already have the array to adress them. Plutonix also has some good points about the design.

Comment: @Christopher: _"Windows Forms is not suited for game development"_ -- tell that to [Windows Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Solitaire).

Comment: @Plutonix Nope i'm not trying to make a game. If I would make a game like you said than I would of course give each Card a Rank, Number etc. I'm just trying to do a programm that sorts the cards and the mixes them.

Comment: Still, cards are cards (data) and pictureboxes are just how you display them to the user.  Aim your googler to posts with the term `Shuffle`.  PictureBoxes need not be shuffled, the *data* does.  Please read [Ask] and take the [TOUR]

Comment: @PeterDuniho: You found the one cardgame that was done with Windows Forms. When I made a exception for Cardgames. Against literally every other game on the planet. And it is not like Solitaire did not show it's issues when you moved the window during the "you won" animation.

Comment: @DimitriosRoman: You want to sort, them but by what property? If you wanted to mix cards it is a lot easier to mix the Data representing the card. Then apply it to the images boxes all ready on the form/generate the image boxes for the Card Data. Basically any access to the UI is expensive and difficulty to do.

Comment: All you have to do is shuffle a `List<String>` or `List<Image>` then reassign each to fixed, static PBs.  You are doing it the hard way.  UI controls make *horrible* program variables

Comment: @Christopher Well sort was a very wrong word for what I meant. I should Reset the cards(Picturebox) to the old position.

Comment: @Plutonix thanks then I will go and try that out now and get back If I need help again

Comment: @PeterDuniho: "Indeed, every single mobile-app game popular in the last decade could just as easily have been implemented in Winforms." Okay, this is either the greatest area of improovement I have found in the last 5 years. Or the greatest lie you could have said. Tell me please how you would do the 3D effects of Pokemon GO in WinForms. I will wait.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: So you can not do 3d in WinForms. You have to do it in Direct3d, then host the result in winforms. Wich is a lot more troublesome then jsut doing it in Direct3D to begin with. And well, every 2nd Mobile game uses 3D. So it is the lie after all.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Just because you like to walk, does not mean everyone likes to walk. Just because I **could** make a 20 km march with a 20 kilo backpack, does not mean it is the ideal scenario. Or even a good or average one. Now we are actually close to it. Really, it was eitehr me grossly missunderstanding something very fundamental. Or you lying. It turned out to be the later. I am happy now.

Comment: @Christopher: there's a big difference between "don't like to" and "cannot". But, I see that the concepts of metaphor and logic escape you. You prefer to impugn the character of others, rather than stick to a fact-based discussion. Good luck with that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: "there's a big difference between "don't like to" and "cannot"." Thanks for finally understandign what I literally wrote in my first comment: "As disclaimer: Windows Forms is not suited for game development. A simple cardgame might actually still work. But there is no guarantee."

Comment: And just because everyone **loves** to programm games in WinForms, they added XNA to .NET. And translated Unity and MonoGame and CryEngine to .NET Core (https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/apps/gaming) - while leaving WinForsm out totally. That shows us nicely how suited Windows Forms is for game development: Exactly as much as I said it is.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to create an array of pictureboxes, each with its own PictureBox object, you can do this easily with LINQ. First, use `Enumerable.Range` to create an IEnumerable with 52 items (which happen to be integers, although it doesn't matter), then use the enumerable to select new pictureboxes.  Convert the results into an array and voila.

```
PictureBox[] cards = Enumerable.Range(1,52).Select( a => new PictureBox() ).ToArray();
```

If each of these needs to be given a unique name and added to some collection too (e.g. your form's Controls collection) you can add that logic easily:

```
PictureBox[] cards = Enumerable.Range(1,52)
    .Select( a => 
    { 
        var p = new PictureBox(); 
        p.Name = string.Format("PictureBox{0}", a);
        this.Controls.Add(p);
        return p;
    }).ToArray();
```

If you decide against creating an array of PictureBox instances, and decide instead to create only one PictureBox and an array of something else, you can still use this technique on most other types:

```
public static T[] CreateArray<T>(int size) where T : new()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, size).Select( i => new T() ).ToArray();
}
```

Or for cards in particular, you might want to enumerate over suits and ranks:

```
    var suits = new[] {"Spades","Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs"};
    var ranks = new[] {"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King","Ace" };

    Card[] cards = ranks.SelectMany(
        r =>
        suits.Select( s =>
            new Card { Rank = r, Suit = s }
        )
    ).ToArray();
```